# cabecera de excel usando python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Se me presenta el siguiente probrema. estoy leyendo un archivo de excel usando python pero cuanto lo hago se me cambian los nombres de la cabecera. saben esto a que se debe ?

**archivo excel original**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el codigo**

```py
from importlib.resources import path
import pandas as pd

archivo = 'C:/Users/adatos/Desktop/python/Query.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(archivo, sheet_name='Query PARAMETRIZACION', header = 0)

print(df)
```

Este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega algunas filas de tu archivo de Excel (Por lo menos los nombres de las columnas y una o dos filas) para intentar reproducirlo, a simple vista no veo algo que pudiera ocasionar ese problema.

Comment: Amigo gracias pero ya lo solucione, el problema era que los datos vienen de una consulta sql y los nombres de las columnas los cambiaron manualmente por el pandas estaba tomando las cabeceras originales de la consulta

Comment: Buen día, que bueno que lo solucionaste, te recomiendo redactar la solución para que la pregunta no quede abierta o cerrar la pregunta en caso contrario.